# Biggest prime factor of a number in Ruby

Tags: ruby, primes, factors

Good morning,

I wrote the following code which works with small-is numbers, to find the biggest prime factor of a number. I can't use `Prime` and I need to come-up with a manual solution.

```
def is_prime?(number)
  list = (2..(Math.sqrt(number))).to_a
  list.each do |i|
    return false if number % i == 0 
  end 
  true 
end 

def biggest_prime(number)
  list = (2..((number))).to_a
  divisors = list.select{|i| is_prime?(i)}
  divisors.select{|i| number % i == 0 }.max
end
```

The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

```
biggest_prime(13195) => 29
```

However when I try with the edge case of `biggest_prime(600851475143)` the system freezes.

Anybody could tell me how to refactor my code to make it more efficient?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 8):

There are many problems with your code that make it massively inefficient:

- In your `biggest_prime` method, you construct an `Array` in memory of every number less than your target number, instead of just iterating through the range. For `600851475143`, the size of that `Array` in memory is ~4 TiByte. Do you have 4 TiByte of RAM? If not, your system will create a huge swapfile and be swapping constantly. Use a `Range` instead! In fact, you are *already* using a `Range`, but then convert it to an `Array` for absolutely no reason at all.
- The same happens in your `is_prime?` method. This `Array` is a lot smaller (only about 6 MiByte at its largest), but you create it over and over and over again, 600 **billion** times! Creating an `Array` of n numbers takes O(n) amount of time, so creating an `Array` of sqrt(n) numbers n times takes O(n * sqrt(n)) time. In total, you need SUM(sqrt(n), n = 1 TO 600851475143) steps, which is about 310498000000000000 steps.
- That is also the number of steps you need for your entire algorithm. Even *if* you had a 10 GHz CPU, *and* this CPU had 100 cores, *and* your problem were perfectly parallelizable, *and* you could perform one entire iteration of your algorithm within a single CPU instruction, you would *still* need 3.5 days to get the result. Since you are not using parallelism, probably don't have a 10 GHz CPU, and an iteration is going to take 10s or hundreds of CPU cycles, a more realistic number would be at least 100 years.

So, what you need to do, is to massively cut down the number of iterations, and the amount of memory.

The latter is easiest: use `Range`s instead of `Array`s.

The former requires a bit of thinking. Here is one idea: You check the same numbers over and over again. That's not necessary. Once you have determined that a number is a divisor, you already know it is a divisor, you don' need to check it again.

Likewise, you check the same number over and over again for primality. But once you have determined that a number is prime, you don't need to check that again, it's not very likely to change, after all.

But first, let's look at what the *most* efficient solution would look like:

```
require 'prime'

def biggest_prime(number)
  number.prime_division.last.first
end
```

Comment: Thanks guys, unfortunately I also need to come up with a solution that doesn't involve using `prime`.

Comment: @Sergi Perhaps you could have specified that in the question!

Comment: Or perhaps look at the source for `prime` in the docs. Its written in Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

I would personally just use the built-in functions for this instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

```
require 'prime'
number = 13195
Prime.each(number).select { |n| number % n == 0 }
```

This will result in the expected output of `[5, 7, 13, 29]`.
The last value will always be the largest, so...

```
Prime.each(number).select { |n| number % n == 0 }.last
```

Gives the `29` you are looking for. This could obviously be cleaned up a little bit, but gives you the idea.

This "freezes" up with the exact same number, which is likely do to going into a `Bignum` and out of the 32-bit integer range (actually 31 bits for Ruby). I would have to dig into the C code to see what the freeze is all about, though, or test with some other 64-bit and higher numbers to see if the results are repeatable.

Answer (score 2):

When we look at the problem like it should be solved in the paper, we can use prime_division. It gives you a set of prime pairs your number divided by. It works fast with big numbers.

```
p (Prime.prime_division(number))[-1].max
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by changing the max number dividing it until you have no more prime numbers to divide against. That way you don't care about the intermediate prime numbers and reduce the iterations greatly :)

```
    def top_prime(n) 
      max = n
      lower = 2

      while lower < max
         while max % lower == 0 && max != lower
           max = max / lower
         end
      lower = lower+1
      end
      max
    end

    puts top_prime(600851475143)
```